# GestureLibrary raises IndexOutOfBounds

Tags: android, gesture

From time to time, GestureLibrary raises an IndexOutOfBoundsException in `recognize()`

Why?
What can I do to prevent this?

> 12-28 22:25:06.118: E/DrawActivity(29717):
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0 12-28
>
> 22:25:06.118: E/DrawActivity(29717):  at
>   java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
>
> 12-28 22:25:06.118: E/DrawActivity(29717):    at
>   java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
>
> 12-28 22:25:06.118:
>   E/DrawActivity(29717):    at
>   android.gesture.Instance.temporalSampler(Instance.java:91)
>
> 12-28
>   22:25:06.118: E/DrawActivity(29717):  at
>   android.gesture.Instance.createInstance(Instance.java:76)
>
> 12-28
>   22:25:06.118: E/DrawActivity(29717):  at
>   android.gesture.GestureStore.recognize(GestureStore.java:137)
>
> 12-28
>   22:25:06.118: E/DrawActivity(29717):  at
>   android.gesture.GestureLibrary.recognize(GestureLibrary.java:64)

Edit: the gesture is captured with:

```
<android.gesture.GestureOverlayView     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gesture_overlay"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:eventsInterceptionEnabled="true"
android:fadeEnabled="false"
android:gestureStrokeAngleThreshold="0."
android:gestureStrokeSquarenessThreshold="0."
android:gestureStrokeType="single"

android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

Comment: Keep your index finger inside the screen bounds. :-)

Comment: Lol @CommonsWare I have a GestureOverlayView that takes the full screen